# Pandas Column Values Replace

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset. A name of column is wage. 
Column's element  contain K values. I want to replace K values.

```
data['Wage']=data['Wage'].replace("K","")
```

But it doesn't work.

[my code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO0Ke.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Wage': ['$200k', '$500']})
df['Wage'] = df['Wage'].str.split('k', expand=True)[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Wage
0  $200
1  $500
```

**OR**

```
df['Wage'] = df['Wage'].str.replace(r'k', '')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Wage
0  $200
1  $500
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
data['Wage']=data['Wage'].replace("K","",regex=True)
```

Or:

```
data['Wage']=data['Wage'].astype(str).str.replace("K","")
```

Comment: @Raşitİri check this too: `df['Wage'].str.strip('k')`